# My questions no longer being accepted

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, new-users, post-ban

So far I had asked seven (7) questions on stackoverflow with considerable down-votes. See image below
[image]

The problem is, I'm a noob when it comes to programming and I'm going through my learning curve. It is obvious that experts in such domains may regard elementary (my) questions as a *bad* question

The worst part is that, people down-vote but do not comment. So it obviously keeps me in the dark as to why down-votes are being given generously to my questions.

**My question is:**

- If that this how SO operates, is there an expectation that the OP has
  to have a reasonable amount of knowledge before posting a question?
- Is there a place where basic questions can be asked?
- If I'm sure that editing my questions are not going to help lift the down-votes and eventually the ban on asking questions - should I wait for 6 months before posting a *good* question? Or am I missing something?

*(P.S: I may be new to stackoverflow, but, I have been in [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/345527/prasanna) for few years and thats going on well for me)*

Comment: Your most recent question is completely off topic. You should not be posting questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. Unfortunately, the only answer on the page has an up vote so you can't delete the question.

Comment: @BSMP - deleting the question wouldn't help. Deleted questions are taken into account when the system works out whether the account should be banned or not.

Comment: @ChrisF They can't keep getting down votes on it if it's deleted.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, you are right. Do you think it is possible for such questions to get closed as `off-topic` and eventually removed? At least, it will save me from down-votes and further ban

Comment: You have gotten feedback but you can't expect people to say, "I down voted and this is why:...". For example, one of your questions had a comment asking for your inputs and another had someone saying your code didn't reproduce the error you had. They may not have been the ones to down vote those questions but they are legitimate reasons to down vote. Assume any criticism of a question is a reason *someone* might down vote even if the person leaving the comment doesn't.

Comment: *Do you think it is possible for such questions to get closed as off-topic and eventually removed?* I think it's possible to flag your own question for closure, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @BSMP That's what I have done for two of my questions. But for other questions, I could not give a reason for close. Anyway, I'm not desperate to post new questions. So should be good. Appreciate you for taking the time out to reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking basic questions, but you are expected to have put in some effort before you do.

That includes (but is not limited to):

- Searching the site for previous questions that might have been asked on your topic. You can either use the search or browse questions with the tags you're interested in.
- Search via Google. It does a far better job of translating what you're looking for into results - and not just on Stack Overflow.
- Pay attention to the questions that the system suggests when you are typing yours up. On numerous occasions I've not found anything on a search, but when I've started typing the questions that come up have answers that answered my question.
- Pay attention to what people are saying in the comments. Are your questions clear and well written? You might be able to improve the grammar and spelling.
- Have you included a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example? If you are vague about what the problem is, people will be unwilling to help.

If you continue to post poor quality questions people will be more likely to downvote them, thus causing you more problems.

The simplest advice I can give is to lurk before posting - either questions or answers. See what types of questions are well received and try to model your questions on those.

Hone you searching skills so you don't have to post a question in the first place. We have millions of questions, there's almost certainly one (or ten) that cover the same ground as yours.

Comment: You are right. *Hone searching skills*. It is only a matter of time before I get better on the subject. Then I would know what to search for and where to look for it.

Comment: @Prasanna As I said, if you're not 100% of the search terms, just type up your question, but **don't** hit "post". Review the suggestions that the system comes up with. Most of the time they're relevant.

Answer (score 10):

> If that this how SO operates, is there an expectation that the OP has to have a reasonable amount of knowledge before posting a question?

You're expected to *do your research* before you ask your question.  You're not expected to just know the answer to every question you have off of the top of your head, but you *are* expected to try to find the answer, and only ask a question here after you've exhausted all of your options for finding the answer yourself.

> Is there a place where basic questions can be asked?

If they're well researched, appropriately scoped, on topic, clear, objective, useful questions, in addition to being basic, then on SO.  If they're not all of those things, then not on this network.

Note that, by their very nature, most basic topics have lots of readily available information about them, so it tends to be pretty hard to find high quality questions on really basic topics, but they're not bad because they're basic questions, they're bad because their answer was already readily available, and the author simply didn't take the time to look for it.

> If I'm sure that editing my questions are not going to help lift the down-votes and eventually the ban on asking questions - should I wait for 6 months before posting a good question? Or am I missing something?

The message you see when you try to ask a question tells you, in great detail, why you're getting the ban, and what you can do about it.  This is a good example of a question you're asking without doing your research before asking it.

Comment: <quote> The message you see when you try to ask a question tells you, in great detail, why you're getting the ban, and what you can do about it. <unquote>. I have [[read those sections](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)]. But they do not apply to the questions I have asked. *I'm unable to delete my questions as well - people have invested their time and effort to answer those questions*  At least, I do not know how I could use the knowledge from those sections to better my questions.

Comment: @Prasanna Those instructions tell you exactly what you need to do.  There are no secret instructions that people have kept hidden from you.  If you can't do what is required of you in order to continue posting questions, then you won't be able to continue posting questions.  If you can, then you'll be able to continue posting questions again.  If you go up to a clerk at the store and tell them, "I know the sign says that this costs $20, but I don't have $20, how can I buy it anyway because I want it" what are you expecting the response to be?

Comment: *I do not want to buy it anyway* . I'm saying that they are not applicable to me. *I'm not desperate to post new questions*. This ban-time will give me enough time to hone my skills and I should be able to post *quality* and well-worded questions after the ban period

Comment: @Prasanna If you don't want to know the answer to the question then why did you ask it?  Note that the ban doesn't *end* in 6 months, it just lets you ask *1* question even though you're below the quality threshold for being able to ask questions.  Unless that question is so well received that it moves you above that threshold, you'll still be be question banned.

Comment: I have got my [[answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362558/my-questions-no-longer-being-accepted?answertab=active#tab-top)] here. I understand how the ban works. Thanks for pointing it out